# Maximizing visibility when your question works on two metas but you have to choose one?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, per-site-meta, cross-posting, site-crossover

I'm trying to decide which of two sites is better for a specific question, and so, before deciding, I'd like to first ask about that question on those sites' metas to find out where it's more on topic.

It's a situation I've been in before: I've got a meta question (especially [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) or [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)) that involves two specific sites. In theory, it makes the most sense to start a discussion about it on both metas. In practice, I've got to choose one.

When posting my *site meta* question, is there an acceptable way to maximize the amount of exposure to and input from *both* sites' meta communities, instead of just the one?

I might be imagining things, and I've been out of the SE loop for a while, but I swear I read *something* about some sort of cross-site related feature that was introduced (or just suggested) in the past couple years, although I have no idea what it was or if its even relevant. (It's possible that I'm thinking of cross-site "linked questions" or something instead.)

---

Here's the question I'm currently pondering; I'm posting it because it's requested but I'd rather have the actual question above answered instead of getting advice on which site to post on here. :)

I've got a fairly involved question regarding the effects of certain types of inaccuracies (e.g. off-centered rotor) and wear on the performance characteristics of small AC electric motors. I can equally tailor it for the Electronics site, or for the Physics site. That's the internal debate this time.

Comment: SE is the only network of sites that I know of where it's totally normal to ask about asking about asking a question...  (The troll in me kind of wants to first ask where to ask *this* question -- and then self-answer that.)

Comment: Can you give an example of the question (feel free to change the sites to protect them from visibility).

Comment: @Catija I edited an example in at the risk of distracting answerers from the more general question (I know how we work here, lol).

Comment: OK... So, just because I uh... want to answer the right questions - when you say "metas" do you actually mean meta sites - because your example sounds like you have a question that you're just trying to choose which main site to plop it on. I don't see anything in your example that mentions meta at all.

Comment: @Catija When I wrote this question it felt clear, but I can see the ambiguity now. Your confusion is well-founded. I tried to clarify. I'm wondering about asking *site meta* [meta-tag:scope] / [meta-tag:on-topic] questions when the meta question involves two different sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, there is not any sort of magic feature for this, unfortunately.

I'd rely on a couple of things here - meta and chat. If you can pick one site you think is more likely, compose the meta question for that site. Once you've posted it, you can increase the visibility on the second site by finding an active chat room for the site and dropping a link to the meta question with a statement asking for help:

> I asked this question on [site] meta but I wasn't sure if it made more sense there or here on this site - as such, I thought y'all might have some helpful input for me about where I should ask the question. Feel free to respond in chat or on [site] meta.

I think both of the specific sites you mention have at least somewhat active metas and chat so hopefully that will help you get to the right solution.